# Google maps not showing on Ionic when the plugin is used

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I want to display maps in my application but Google map isn't showing up. I have made my application on Ionic and I have used the Cordova Google Maps plugin. [Here](https://github.com/TitikshaDaga/Google-Maps-Ionic-Demo) is the link to my code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in config.xml plugins list:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="~2.0.6">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="Your_key" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: also u can use <iframe> tag , and inside it open directly the google map.because i can also face issue then i had write the same .

Comment: Thank u so much. Adding iframe made it work. Thanks a million times.

Comment: Hey it worked yesterday but today it stopped working again

Comment: check the code i had sent yesterday in discussion chat and let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered in Google Maps and added API KEY do your app?

Comment: any error in console? Does the directive added anything to page?

Comment: When I run using ionic lab I get the following error: GET http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js 
(anonymous) @ ionic-lab:124
(anonymous) @ ionic-lab:125 otherwise no error

Comment: Are you deploying app to phone or use it or desktop? It may not work on desktop - try to deploy it to phone

Comment: I deployed it on my phone as well and still I get a blank screen.

Comment: I cant see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/google-maps it should be added in dependencies

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMaps, LatLng, CameraPosition, GoogleMapsEvent } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    let element = document.getElementById('map');
    let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element, {});
    let latlng = new LatLng(40.7128, -74.0059);


    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
        let position: CameraPosition = {
      target: latlng,
      zoom: 10,
      tilt: 30
        }
        map.moveCamera(position);
    })
  }

}
```

And in your HTML file

```
<div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
```

This is the tutorial : http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

1.open project directory and run this in cmd

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="api key" -variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="api key here"
```

2.add this in specific map page

```
declare var google;
```

3.In the same class

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
    if (this.global.checkNetwork() == true) {
      this.initializeMap();
    }
    else {
      this.showAlert("Internet is not available");
    }
  }

  initializeMap() {

    let locationOptions = { timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

      (position) => {

        let options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
      },

      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }, locationOptions
    );
  }
```

4.in home.html

```
    <ion-content>
    <!-- <button ion-button (click)="presentModal()">presentModal</button> -->
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>
```

5.in home.scss

```
page-home {
    #map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

6. include in your src/index.html file (above the cordova.js file):

that is it

Comment: <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key here" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>